# Loading a Single column out of 50 Using Load() of Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Suppose there are 50 columns in database table. Each column contains image(binary data). You need to display only one one image out of 50 at a time. How would you achieve the same via hibernate? Keep in mind that executing load on the table will result in loading complete row while we need only one column data.

Comment: This sounds like a pretty awful database.

Comment: Hi David, This is just an example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pavnesh, I am answering the question in a geenral fashion. If you just one one column from the table create a named query and return that single column, and retrieve the data in your DAO class with proper datatype.

and if you want just a single row use query.setMaxresult function and give the value as 1 and then you can select the particular column value from the row,but however in this case only the top row it will return.

Comment: @palayan--- Thanks for your reply... Can we do it by using load method of hibernate

Comment: Pavnesh I am not sure we can do it or not but if you can create a query object then you surely can use that query.setMaxResult fucntion.